# How do you extract the error message for MongoError: E11000 duplicate key found?

Tags: mongodb, error-handling

How do you extract the error message for `MongoError: E11000` duplicate key found. I want just the error itself message not the entire object.

Answer (score 2):

I will explain this with an example, in `mongo` shell:

```
db.test.insertOne( { _id: 1 } )    // insert a document

try { 
    db.test.insertOne( { _id: 1 } ) // insert another document
} 
catch(err) { 
    print(err.code)
    print(err.errmsg)
}
```

This prints the error code value and the message:

```
E11000
E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.err index: _id_ dup key: { _id: 1.0 }
```

The actual error as seen on the terminal (if you don't catch it in a `try-catch` block) is something like this:

```
WriteError({
        "index" : 0,
        "code" : 11000,
        "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.err index: _id_ dup key: { _id: 1.0 }",
        "op" : {
                "_id" : 1
        }
})
```

`WriteResult.writeError` is part of the object [WriteResult](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/WriteResult/index.html).

`WriteResult.writeError.code` has the error code value you are looking for. `WriteResult.writeError.errmsg` has the error message.

You can get the error code and message values similarly from any of the programming language applications (like Java, Python, JavaScript / NodeJS, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

With a regular expression most likely.

Note that the error message can change between server versions.