# how to retrieve the error object in the mongodb duplicate error

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am working with nodejs and mongoose to store the user information as showed in the code

```
  const User = mongoose.model('User')
  let user = new User(req.body);

   user.save(function (error) {
    if (error) {
      switch(error.code){
          case 11000:
            console.log('error', 'User already exists 11000',error);
            console.log(error.code, error.name,error.index,error.driver);
            return res.status(422).send({
              error: error
            });
      }
   }
```

when it comes to store the duplicated objects in mongodb, it will throw out an exception with code 11000. The code above can capture this exception with error object.

In the debugging, the code line  console.log('error', 'User already exists 11000',error);
below will output an error message like the one below

```
{ MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: game-dev.users index: email_1 dup key: { : "helxsz@gmail.com" }
at Function.create 
 ......
```

this error message is useful however it doesn't exist in the error object - user.save(function (error). the error object only has [ 'driver', 'name', 'index', 'code' ] keys.

my question is how can i retrieve this error message?

Comment: Here is a similar post: [How do you extract the error message for MongoError: E11000 duplicate key found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62925292/how-do-you-extract-the-error-message-for-mongoerror-e11000-duplicate-key-found/62926597#62926597)

Answer (score 0):

First, you can find the data with a unique key. if data found then return error else add data to DB

```
const User = mongoose.model('User');
 const is_user=User.findOne({email_1 :req.body.email_1});
 if(is_user){
    return res.status(400).json({
            message: "User aready exist with this email address"});
          }else{
  let user = new User(req.body);
    user.save();
    }
```