# Does the acknowledged property for a Pymongo result object mean that the action was successful?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Essentially I want to know if checking for a `acknowledged = True` will be sufficient to catch errors in reading / writing or if I should use a try except.

Comment: The using of `acknowledged = True` cannot be substituted for `try-except` . You can catch errors of different types and perform certain actions based upon the error class type, for example. Try except is about exception/error handling in code. It also catches errors not related to MongoDB/PyMongo.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Understand that `try-except` will catch different errors but if we are talking strictly for the database operation passing or failing, would `acknowledged = True` be sufficient or should the op be wrapped in a `try-catch` ?

Comment: It is not a must. But, its good programming practice. And, you can catch specific errors/exceptions, and act accordingly - e.g., `pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError`.

Comment: Here is an example (working in shell): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62925292/how-do-you-extract-the-error-message-for-mongoerror-e11000-duplicate-key-found/62926597#62926597

Comment: Thanks for the example. So assuming then that a `try-except` will catch any error with the db op and then no need to check for `acknowledged = True ?`

Comment: I see the `acknowledge` attribute is associated with the `WriteConcern` - see the docs at: https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/results.html?highlight=pymongo.results#module-pymongo.results

Comment: Ok I understand now. Thanks for your help.